# Database cache ( redis, memcache ) usage, query vs. items

Tags: database, api, redis, memcached

I'm wondering what the preferred way is to cache elements from a database with an in-memory cache, like redis or memcache.  The context is that I have a table of items which are being accessed by an API, frequently ( millions of times per second ) as real-time stats.  In general, the API is just looking for items in a given range of time, with a certain secondary id.  The same data is likely to be hit many times. It seems like you could do it in a few ways:

1. Cache the entire query.

Meaning, the entire data string resulting from the real query to the Database would get stored in the cache, with a minimal query as the key.  The advantage is that for frequently used queries, there is just a single access to get the entire set of results back.  But any slightly different query needs to be redone and cached.

2. Cache the items in the query.

Meaning, each item returned from the real query gets stored individually in the cache, with a searchable id as the key.  The advantage is that for slightly different queries, you don't need to run a full query against the DB again, just elements that are not currently cached.

3. Mirror the entire database

Meaning, each item is put into the cache as soon as it gets created/udpdated in the DB.  The cache is always assumed to be up to date, and so all queries can just run on the cache directly.

It seems like these approaches might be better or worse in certain circumstances, but are there some pitfalls here that make some completely undesirable?  Or just clearly better in this use-case?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

#3 i.e., Mirroring the database is not a good option. Also, keep in mind that most in memory systems like Redis don't have a query langurage but rather retreival is based on Keys. So, it is not a good idea to replicate data, especially if data is relational.
You should use a combination of #1 and #2. Redis is key based, so you will have to design the keys as per your query criteria. I would suggest to build a library that works on the concept of etag. In redis, save the etag and the query response. The library should pass the etag to backend logic, which will re-run the query only if etag doesn't match. If the etag matches then backend will not re-run query and library will take the cached response from redis and send back to client.

Refer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag for concept.